# $emit not being caught by listener

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having an issue here that I can't seem to fix:
I would like to have a simple toggle for a component using `$emit`

this is my `index.vue` :

```html
    <div
      v-for="(filteredArticles, categoryKey) in groupedCategories"
      :key="categoryKey"
      class="l"
      @listen-button-event="toggle"
    >
      <CategoryWrapper :title="categoryKey" />
    </div>
```

```js
  methods: {
    toggle () {
      alert('I did something')
      console.log('ping')
      this.isActive = !this.isActive
    }
  }
```

this is my component :

```html
    <div
      :class="{ active: isActive }"
      @click="changeComponent()"
    >
      <a>{{ title }}</a>
    </div>
```

```js
  data () {
    return {
      isActive: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeComponent () {
      this.$emit('listenButtonEvent')
    }
  }
```

Doesn't seem to do anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listeners need to be `camelCas`'ed like this

```html
<CategoryWrapper :title="categoryKey" @listenButtonEvent="toggle" />
```

and not `kebab-case`'ed.

As you can see in the Vue devtools, since you're emitting `listenButtonEvent` here.

[image]

---

A better convention being emitting a `update:listenButtonEvent` btw, cannot find an official recommendation for that one again.

Answer (score 3):

`listen-button-event` shouldn't be on the `div` it should be on the `CategoryWrapper` Component.

```
<div
  v-for="(filteredArticles, categoryKey) in groupedCategories"
  :key="categoryKey"
  class="l"
  
>
  <CategoryWrapper :title="categoryKey" @listen-button-event="toggle" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks :)
this is actually not working though

Comment: You are welcome, Could you provide a full example of code on a live editor like codesandbox? so I can debug if there are other issues with the code

Comment: thanks Mina, [here is the full code](https://shorturl.at/ACFS5)

Comment: @Aurore, thanks for providing an example, but it doesn't work and the page is completely blank.